# Multiple input into Conditional panel in R

Tags: r

I have a shiny ui.R which is trying to do the following. The conditional panel should receive input from `checkboxGroupInput`.

In case of a single input from the `checkboxGroupInput` it is easy to call the condition say "input.sectors='MFI'". An example is given below:

```
conditionalPanel(
    condition ="input.sectors == 'BC'",
    checkboxGroupInput("BCEntity","Select Entity",choices = c("Taraashna"))
),
```

However if two or more options are selected in the `checkboxGroupInput` then the condition `input.sectors=='BC','MFI'` doesn't seem to properly work. Logical Symbols also didn't work properly. List option as c('BC','MFI') also had issues. Is there a easy solution for the same. The way I tried is shown below:

```
conditionalPanel(
    condition ="input.sectors == 'BC','MFI'",
    checkboxGroupInput("BCEntity","Select Entity",choices = c("Taraashna")),
    checkboxGroupInput("AGRIEntity","Select Entity",choices = c("Kisan Dhan", "Origo"))
),
```

Comment: What exactly did you try with logical operators?

Comment: I used "input.sectors=='BC' & 'MFI'"

Comment: It's really hard to do this without seeing at least a sample of the data you're using, but if you're trying to pick cases where either one of those conditions hold, you'd need to use `input.sectors=='BC' | input.sectors=='MFI'`.